# Cross-compiling boost 1.7 for ARM Raspberry pi 3

Tags: c++11, boost, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to get my boost cross-compilation ready for my raspberry project. I have the cross-compilation of my project up until now running but now I need to start using some boost features.
In order to do that, I'm trying to compile it and I'm following many guides (The main one is [this](https://www.cnx-software.com/2011/10/03/cross-compiling-boost-c-libraries-for-arm/) one) but I'm getting some errors while executing the bjam:

`./bjam install toolset=gcc-arm --prefix=~/libs/ --disable-long-double --sNO_ZLIB=1 --sNO_BZIP2=1`

I have the toolchain recognized with the modification of the `project-config.jam` file to `using gcc : arm : arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ ;`

I'm using the WSL debian on my windows 10 for all this. You will see that on the paths.

This the error that I'm getting:

```
*** argument error
* rule numbers.less ( n1 n2 )
* called with: ( 4 )
* missing argument n2
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/util/numbers.jam:66:see definition of rule 'numbers.less' being called
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/tools/common.jam:854: in common.format-name
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/boost_install/boost-install.jam:87: in boost-install.generate-cmake-variant-
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:107: in modules.call-in
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/util/indirect.jam:105: in indirect.call
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:902: in execute
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:821: in class@action.actualize
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:332: in actualize-action
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:518: in actualize-no-scanner
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build/virtual-target.jam:142: in class@virtual-target.actualize
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/build-system.jam:810: in load
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/kernel/modules.jam:295: in import
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/tools/build/src/kernel/bootstrap.jam:139: in boost-build
/mnt/d/Downloads/boost_1_70_0/boost-build.jam:17: in module scope
```

I'm quite lost regarding this. I've been searching for a solution for the last week and I'm giving up now. Does anybody knows what's going on?

I have this compiler and cross-compiler installed:

```
g++/stable,now 4:6.3.0-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
g++-6/stable,stable,now 6.3.0-18+deb9u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
g++-6-arm-linux-gnueabi/stable,now 6.3.0-18cross1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
g++-arm-linux-gnueabi/stable,now 4:6.3.0-4 amd64 [installed]
gcc/stable,now 4:6.3.0-4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-6/stable,stable,now 6.3.0-18+deb9u1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-6-arm-linux-gnueabi/stable,now 6.3.0-18cross1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-6-arm-linux-gnueabi-base/stable,now 6.3.0-18cross1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gcc-6-base/stable,stable,now 6.3.0-18+deb9u1 amd64 [installed]
gcc-6-cross-base/stable,now 6.3.0-18cross1 all [installed,automatic]
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi/stable,now 4:6.3.0-4 amd64 [installed]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be ignored. It's a bug in the one of the bjam files. You can follow [this link](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/issues/258) for more information